# Why was it inevitable that they would find Translucent's skin?

Tags: the-boys-2019

After Translucent's death, they say that it's inevitable that the Seven will find his skin.

Why is that? Why can't they just go on a drive, bury it in a desolate location, and that's that?

Comment: They dumped it into the ocean in a zinc-lined box and it got found a few hours later. I can only assume that if they'd buried it in the desert, another Super (or just some random) would have found it. When something's indestructible, there's no such thing as "gone forever".

Comment: Wow, was about to post pretty much this exact question (only watched the episode a couple of days ago). Assuming the skin isn't flammable, does it stay invisible if everything else is burned off? If so it seems like it should be pretty easy to hide (although the Boys seem not to bother incinerating the non-invulnerable internal bits iirc). And whether it's invisible or not, surely you just encase it in some wet concrete or something? The Seven don't even know for sure he's dead; they're hardly going to bust every new construction project in the city into centimetre-sized pieces on a hunch.

Comment: I mean even if it was just buried in a hole by the side of the road, or in some random patch of woods, how would anyone find it?

Comment: @temporary_user_name - The same way things that are buried in the woods often get found. People don't seem to be aware that [the ground is constantly churning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8iRE7U_new), albeit very very slowly.